# paypal authentication failure in sandbox

Tags: authentication, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I encounter an issue when I try to use the Paypal sandbox API.
I've created my 2 sandbox accounts (the facilitator and the buyer), and I've created my app to get the credentials.

Then, I use the curl example provided by Paypal to get a token :

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "my-client-id:my-secret" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I get a 200 response, with an "access_token".

Then, I use this access token to get another resource, for example :

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices?page=3&page_size=4&total_count_required=true \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer the-token-received-above"
```

Then, I get a 401 error :
    {
        "name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE",
        "message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.",
        "links":[{
            "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error",
            "rel":"information_link"
        }]
    }

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, since I've followed every step decribed in the Paypal doc (at least, I think I have... probably not)

Thanks for your help

Comment: I get this exact same error when I follow the same PayPal instructions

Answer (score 2):

After get access_token. Please try this

```php
try {
    $params = array('access_token' => $jsonResponse->access_token);
    $userInfo = OpenIdUserinfo::getUserinfo($params, $this->_api_context);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    ResultPrinter::printError("User Information", "User Info", null, $params, $ex);
    exit(1);
}

 ResultPrinter::printResult("User Information", "User Info", $userInfo->getUserId(), $params, $userInfo);
```

Don't forget to add

```php
use PayPal\Api\OpenIdTokeninfo;
use PayPal\Api\OpenIdUserinfo;
```

That's worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -v -X GET "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices?page=3&page_size=4&total_count_required=true" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer the-token-received-above"
```

Actually had this exact same issue but didn't know what was wrong with my curl. For me, the issue was I forgot to put "Bearer" in the Authorization section.

For this, you are required to wrap the URL with quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks. Same here...forgot to put "Bearer [token]" in the Authorization.